# Angular Repeat - Complex HTML loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular1.6

I want to loop through this HTML structure
Each loop should add an image inside
Then repeat the outer elements again and continue.

I am finding it difficult to isolate the index and append the correct image in the sequence - I ahve tried modulus but goes out of sync.

I kinda need to get the repeat in chunks of 5 do this block then continue for another chunk until all is complete.... not sure how.

```
<span ng-repeat="node in inspiration.data track by $index">
<div class="list__row row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-3 list__medium" style="background-image: url('https://z3photorankmedia-a.akamaihd.net/media/e/e/2/ee2ju34/mobile.jpg');"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-2 list__small" style="background-image: url('https://z1photorankmedia-a.akamaihd.net/media/5/a/g/5ag3i44/mobile.jpg');"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-5 list__large" style="background-image: url('https://photorankmedia-a.akamaihd.net/media/4/x/v/4xv6w34/mobile.jpg');"></div>
</div>

<div class="list__row row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-5 list__large" style="margin-top: -8.3%; background-image: url('https://z2photorankmedia-a.akamaihd.net/media/c/d/t/cdt4i44/mobile.jpg');"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-3 list__medium" style="margin-top: 8.3%; background-image: url('https://z3photorankmedia-a.akamaihd.net/media/i/y/c/iycjf34/mobile.jpg');"></div>
</div> 
</span>
```

Comment: What's not working in this exactly? You don't appear to be using $index, or anything in the ng-repeat anyway, so wondering what the issue is?

Comment: The HTML was showing what I wanted to do without any Angular embedded at the moment as I wondering where to start - looking at ng-switch when now also - basically I need row based on a variable - either 1st or 4th and a row based on the other indexes.